# Pre-caching ggplot2 output using memoise for use in a web service

Tags: r, ggplot2, memoization, cran

For some web services I need to speed up on demand ggplot2 plots as much as possible. With the introduction of memoise, some caching is automatically introduced on the plotting functions, making the second plot significantly faster than the first one. However my web service only draws 1 plot per R session, so this doesn't help by default.

I was wondering if it would be wise/possible/useful to do precaching (e.g. do some calculations onload, before the actual request), or save/load memoise caches to disk for common calls + output.

An example:

```
> library(ggplot2);
> pdf(tempfile());
> system.time(print(qplot(speed, dist, color=speed, data=cars, geom=c("point", "smooth"))));
   user  system elapsed 
  0.496   0.008   0.512 
> system.time(print(qplot(speed, dist, color=speed, data=cars, geom=c("point", "smooth"))));
   user  system elapsed 
  0.312   0.004   0.322
```

Comment: I edited your title, I interpreted it as that you where looking for a ggplot2 version which was before the time it used memoise (pre-memoise ggplot2). I hope this reflects your intention, and feel free to change it back if not.

Comment: I am curious to see whether you saw any speed improvements by `memoise()`ing some `g <- ggplot()...` function. I did the same (*within* one session), but saw hardly any improvements in plotting speed.
Maybe I'm doing it wrong ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the `memoise` package only supports in-session cache. If you quit an R session, you lose the cache. I'm not sure if the `cacheSweave`/`knitr` model helps for your web service, but I believe you have to write the cached results in the disk anyway like these two packages. If the same code is run (verify by MD5), you simply load the cache. You might provide an example so I can know the problem better.

Comment: The [development version](https://github.com/hadley/memoise/releases) of `memoise` now has persistent cache with the `cache_filesystem` option.